# Direct assignment array and use of array.length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am talking about heavy coding like for graphics or physics processing (not standard) where speed is expensive.

```
var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

What happens when you ask

```
console.log(a.lengh);
```

**Is it like accessing a normal variable that gets updated on a change or is it really counted each time?**

Say if you had a lot of loops that relied on knowing this

```
var i=flepdefloo;  // some large number;

var a2=[];

while(i--){
    a2[a2.length] = 'something';
    }
```

Should a2.length be cached / incremented manually in a separate var?

Comment: The value of `.length` is calculated whenever the array is mutated, not when it's accessed (at least according to the specification, http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5).

Comment: Wouldn't `a2[] = 'something'` give the same result?

Comment: @Marc: That throws a syntax error in JS. That only works in PHP (afaik).

Comment: @FelixKling Golly, my brain works in PHP... good point.

Comment: If you're populating an array in a loop, and the types of its members are the same, modern browsers will likely have optimizations available if you pre-define the array size by doing `var a2 = new Array(flepdefloo);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `.length` is calculated whenever the array is mutated, not when it's accessed. At least [according to the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5).

And indeed, when I inspect the property in Chrome, it's a normal data property (not a getter or setter):

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor([], 'length');
Object {value: 0, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

---

However, there are other ways to add elements to an array. You can use `.push`:

```
arr.push(value);
```

You could also initialize the array with a specific length and set the value with the loop variable (which would require you to change your loop):

```
var arr = new Array(length);
// ...
arr[i] = value;
```

Comment: Good answer, the object inspection is insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers actually handle this for you now by doing optimizations on the code prior to compiling. You can test this yourself:

http://jsperf.com/array-length-caching-test

also, you might want to consider using

```
a2.push( "something" );
```

That uses a native function.